# How to find the source of the error from browser console log?

Tags: html, angular, firefox, web, angular2-routing

I have a routing error in my web app, which is shown in the screenshot of my browser console. How do I tell from this error log in which file and at which line is this call?

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to debug a routing issue from the F12 Debugger. As such, please post all **relevant code** (including your configuration and routing) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can see what's happening with routing is to turn on route tracing. I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
], { enableTracing: true })
```